# How to differentiate between "no child rows exist" and "no parent row exists" in one SELECT query?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a table C that references rows from tables A and B:

`id, a_id, b_id, ...`

and a simple query:

`SELECT * FROM C WHERE a_id=X AND b_id=Y`

I would like to differentiate between the following cases:

- No row exists in A where id = X
- No row exists in B where id = Y
- Both such rows in A and B exist, but no rows in C exist where a_id = X and b_id = Y

The above query will return empty result in all those cases.

In case of one parent table I could do a `LEFT JOIN` like:

`SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN C ON a.id = c.a_id WHERE c.a_id = X`

and then check if the result is empty (no row in A exists), has one row with NULL `c.id` (row in A exists, but no rows in C exist) or 1+ rows with non-NULL `c.id` (row in A exists and at least one row in C exists). A bit messy but it works, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this, especially if there is more than one parent table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I managed to get a satisfactory solution using the following two features:

- Subselect bound to a column, which allows me to check if a row exists and (importantly) get a NULL value otherwise (e.g. `SELECT (SELECT id FROM a WHERE id = 1) as a_id)`)
- [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html)

Initial data:

```
CREATE TABLE people 
(
  id integer not null primary key, 
  name text not null
);

CREATE TABLE thing_types 
(
  id integer not null primary key, 
  name text not null
);

CREATE TABLE things
(
  id integer not null primary key, 
  person_id integer not null references people(id), 
  thing_type_id integer not null references thing_types(id), 
  name text not null
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES (1, 'Bill');
INSERT INTO thing_types VALUES (1, 'game');

INSERT INTO things VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'Duke Nukem');
INSERT INTO things VALUES (2, 1, 1, 'Warcraft 2');
```

And the query:

```
WITH v AS (
  SELECT (SELECT id FROM people WHERE id=<person_id_param>) AS person_id, 
         (SELECT id FROM thing_types WHERE id=<thing_type_param>) AS thing_type_id
)
SELECT v.person_id, v.thing_type_id, things.name 
FROM 
  v LEFT JOIN things 
    ON v.person_id = things.person_id AND v.thing_type_id = things.thing_type_id
```

This query will always return at least one row. In case if both parent table ids are valid and there are some records, I get

```
person_id  thing_type_id  name
-------------------------------------
        1              1   Duke Nukem
        1              1   Warcraft 2
```

If either `person_id` or `thing_type_id` are invalid, I get one row where `name` is NULL and either `person_id` or `thing_type_id` is NULL:

```
person_id  thing_type_id  name
-------------------------------------
     NULL              1         NULL
```

If both `person_id` and `thing_type_id` are valid but there are no records in `things`, I get one row where both `person_id` and `thing_type_id` are not NULL, but the `name` is NULL:

```
person_id  thing_type_id  name
-------------------------------------
        1              1         NULL
```

Since I have a `NOT NULL` constraint on `things.name`, I know that this case can only mean that there are no matching records in `things`.